# An error occurred when calling lavaan with rpy2

Tags: python, rpy2, r-lavaan

When I try to call another package, the display is successful.Only lavaan package was failed. What is the reason for this? How to solve it?

I wrote code in jupyter,and called R backages using rpy2.

```
[In]:    from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
          lavaan = importr('lavaan')

[Out]:   ----
RRuntimeError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-93-71e6d20e5e18> in <module>
      1 from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
----> 2 lavaan = importr('lavaan')

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\packages.py in importr(name, lib_loc, robject_translations, signature_translation, suppress_messages, on_conflict, symbol_r2python, symbol_check_after, data)
    451     if _package_has_namespace(rname, 
    452                               _system_file(package = rname)):
--> 453         env = _get_namespace(rname)
    454         version = _get_namespace_version(rname)[0]
    455         exported_names = set(_get_namespace_exports(rname))

RRuntimeError:
```